# Will a Raspberry Pi 3 work with a 5tb Fat32 Hdd

Tags: pi-3, media-server

I have a hdd that I have been using as a media device on several different platforms. It is formatted to fat32 and my windows computer only recognizes 3out of 5 tb and will not let me add more. My mac however does allow me to do what I want.  I would like to hook it up to a Raspberry Pi as a PLEX server and be able to play all of my files anywhere. Would the RPi be able to open and use this HDD? Would it also be able to use another 3TB hdd at the same time?

Comment: Why not just hook it up and find out?

Comment: I haven't ordered one yet. I want to know that it will work before I do.

Answer (score 1):

i have personally successfully used multiple 4tb hard drives with my raspberry pi and see no reason why your 5tb and 3th drives would not be compatible with the pi simultaneously. The only potential problem that i can see arising would be that Fat32 is a file system that is limited to partitions that are 2tb in size, so formating a 5tb drive to fat32 may require 3 partitions, which is likely the reason that your windows pc is not recognizing the drive as being 5tb in size. you can read more about this phenomenon [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/techsupport/comments/41ydrw/5tb_fat32_external_drive_for_ps3/)